# Recursively removing/renaming files using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have to go through many levels of child folders and remove special characters that are invalid in SharePoint, mainly '#&'

I have scoured the internet trying different commands; rename-item/move-item, variations of the two, all to no avail. The closest i've gotten is using:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace'[!@#&]','_'}
```

but i keep getting this error: Rename-item: Source and destination path must be different.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error only happens when you attempt to rename a directory to the same `NewName` as the current name, you can safely ignore it.

Add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to silently suppress the error message:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace'[!@#&]','_'} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of this.  What if `MyFile_1.txt` and `MyFile#1.txt` both exist?

Comment: @BaconBits then nothing happens

Comment: Yes, but you don't get an error or a warning or anything, and you probably want an error because you couldn't rename a file you actually wanted to.

Comment: I tested it and ended up with two files having the same name (renamed).

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter out the files that you're not planning to rename:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '[!@#&]' } |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '[!@#&]','_'}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this may work

```
dir -Recurse -File | ? basename -Match '[!@#&]' | % {
    # if the file.txt already exists, rename it to file-1.txt and so on
    $num = 1
    $base = $_.basename -replace'[!@#&]', '_'
    $ext = $_.extension
    $destdir = Split-Path $_.FullName
    $newname = Join-Path $destdir "$base$ext"
    while (Test-Path $newname) {
        $newname = Join-Path $destdir "$base-$num$ext"
        $num++
    }

    ren $_.fullname $newname
}
```